# Count links on a page using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Let's say I'm testing the action `index` of the controller `StaticPages`. On the controller tests, I need to count the number of links to `about_path` on this page.

I've Google it and found nothing that could help me. I know this is quite simple and a newbie question but I just started to study RSpec and I stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to keep in mind that *controller specs don't render views by default*. I recommend that you either use a view or request spec.

Second, if you're using builtin assertions then you can check the number of links with:

```
assert_select %(a[href="#{about_path}"]), 5 # 5 is the expected number of links
```

If you use expectations then the following should work:

```
expect(page).to have_selector(%(a[href="#{about_path}"]), count: 5)
```

I recommend you take a look at [the RSpec docs](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.5/rspec-rails/#Request_Specs).

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the response body, then count.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
doc.css('a').length
```